# ADFS MFA Adapter AuthenticationMethods

Tags: c#, adfs3.0

I created a ADFS 3.0 MFA Adapter to provide a Second factor Authentication. 
In IAuthenticationAdapterMetadata.AuthenticationMethods I specified one Auth method (found some example online).

```
public string[] AuthenticationMethods
{
    get { return new string[] { "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp" }; }
}
```

I understand when my MFA Adapter successfully Authenticates it needs to return 
the registered Auth method:

```
    public IAdapterPresentation TryEndAuthentication(IAuthenticationContext context, IProofData proofData, HttpListenerRequest request, out Claim[] claims){
    ...

      if (status.AuthSuccess){
            System.Security.Claims.Claim claim = new System.Security.Claims.Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/authenticationmethod", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2012/12/authmethod/otp");
            claims = new System.Security.Claims.Claim[] { claim };
            return null;
       } 
}
```

Which I'm doing it. This works fine if I don't have an back-end App (like Office 365) on my ADFS Server. A bare minimum message shows up that user is logged in.

I installed my ADFS plugin on a server which is setup with a backend App (Office 365). 
When user tries to login (thru Outlook portal also called Relying party initiated login) my Plugin gets called for 2nd factor. As explained above on successful Authentication of 2nd factor the plugin returns the registered AuthMethod. 
The expected behavior here is that user successfully logins into App (O365) basically App landing page shows up. But instead I see that the User gets logged out and goes back to the Portal Login screen.

So my question is : What am I doing wrong ? I seem to be doing right in my Plugin. Is it something to do with what we are defining in AuthenticationMethods. 
Can I define any custom URI for AuthenticationMethods or is there a standard to it ? 
Is there any other Claims or Relying Party Settings outside the Plugin I need to configure ? 
I couldn't find any concrete documentation explaining these things in detail, except for online Examples and exercise to create a Plugin.

Comment: For successful authentication, the claim value returned by `TryEndAuthentication` must match one of the values returned from `AuthenticationMethods`.  What do you mean by "results in User to Logout and Login screen is presented"?  Can you include a screenshot or [screencap](https://screentogif.codeplex.com/)?

Comment: Hi Mitch. I've updated my question to be more clear. As you would notice I'm actually returning the same AuthMethod which is registered IAuthenticationAdapterMetadata.AuthenticationMethods(). And this works when there is no backend App. With the backend App O365 on Successful auth the User gets logged out for some reason. Wierd.

Comment: Have you examined the capture to determine if a token is being issued to the client?  That would isolate the failure to either AD FS or to how O365 is interpreting the claims.  See [How to Use Fiddler Web Debugger to Analyze a WS-Federation Passive Sign-In](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3286.ad-fs-2-0-how-to-use-fiddler-web-debugger-to-analyze-a-ws-federation-passive-sign-in.aspx)